# How do I get the expected value of this random value knowing its c.d.f.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, education

Can anyone answer with steps how to get the expected value of this random variable?

Let $X$ be a random variable with following c.d.f,

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}0  &x < -1\\
\dfrac{1-x^2}4 & -1 \le x < \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt 2}\\ \dfrac12 - x^4 & \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt 2} \le x < 0 \\ \dfrac34 + x & 0 \le x \lt\dfrac14 \\ 1 &x \ge \dfrac14 \end{cases}$$

Find $\mathbb E(X)$

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CSPY.png)

Comment: Hint: Notice the massive point.   Then apply the usual definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the expectation directly from the cdf using the formula:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname E[X] &= \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \, dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x)\, dx
\end{align*}
In order to solve these integrals,
you have to break the region of integration into
the regions that were used to define $F(x)$.

Comment: This trick can be very useful. You can find the derivation of the formula here: https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/the-mean-of-a-random-variable-in-terms-of-its-cdf/

Answer (score 2):

In the interiors of these intervals, you can differentiate to get the p.d.f. But in addition there may be point masses at the boundaries between the intervals. Those give you a discrete part of the probability distribution. Thus the expected value is
$$
\operatorname E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x F'(x)\, dx + \sum \Big\{ x f(x) : x \text{ is a boundary point where there is a point mass} \Big\}.
$$
Notice that the integral is only over a bounded interval since $F'$ is $0$ on the two unbounded components.

Comment: would it be possible for you to help me with this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520147/finding-probability-distribution-from-density-function-integration-issues I figure if anybody could, you could.